# Clock skew warning

Tags: contiki

I am trying to run hello-world program onnTelosB in Contiki OS.
As, I run .upload, it is showing

`clock skew detected. your build may be incomplete`.

what will be the possible reason? How can I correct it?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of message is typically seen when the system clock and the timestamps on files are out of sync (typically the system clock is behind and the timestamps of files are in the future).